# Input box aligned with text?

Tags: html, css

How can I get my boxes to align with my text?

I have also copy and pasted the html/css code in jsFiddle!

http://jsfiddle.net/EFByC/51/

```
<form 
  action="http://www.sblogger/cgi-bin/subcomments"
  method="post" >

<fieldset name="commentFS" id="commentFS">

    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input name="username" id="username" title="Supply your username" required="required"/>

    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
    <input name="email" id="email" type="email" title="Supply a valid e-mail address" required="required"/>

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input name="password" id="password" type="password" title="You must provide your password" required="required"/>

    <label for="commentbox">Comment<br />
            (500 character limit)</label>
    <textarea maxlength="500" name="commentbox" id="commentbox"></textarea> 


    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment"/>  
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: do some inspecting here http://purecss.io/forms/ and be happy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go, [edited your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EFByC/55/)

It comes down to this:

If you float `left` & `right`, you need a wrapper to preserve the room for the floats.

so i added this:

```
p {
    overflow: hidden;/*this should be clearfix, just for demo it is overflow fix*/
}

label{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    width: 20%;/* was 100%*/
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    /*clear: left*/
}
```

and the wrapper:

```
<p>
 <label for="username">Username</label>
 <input name="username" id="username" title="Supply your username" required="required">
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

i see you use `float`, `display` and `width:100%;`  , you definitly have too much unnedeed rules here .

`inline-block` + `width`, can do it and allow you to `vertiacal-align` labels and inputs,
`float`+`clear` can work too, but `vertical-align` will not be avalaible :
example with inline-block:

```
 /*Field set styles */ 
fieldset { 
    background-color: rgb(245,245,255);
    margin: 15px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 90%;
}
/* Label Styles */  
label{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width:35%;
}
/*Input control styles */   
input, textarea { 
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 55%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
/*Text area styles */

textarea {
    height: 150px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EFByC/58/